# Polygons from Polylines in GRASS GIS?

Tags: polygon, grass-gis, editing

I have 20,000 polylines in a .gdb that represent about 5,000 building footprints. Some of the building footprints have pretty substantial gaps (image below). I would like to snap the polylines closed into polygons so that I can extrude the buildings.

Can this be done in GRASS?

[image: building footprints]

I am hoping that there is something in the open source community with a "Clean" or some such functionality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In GRASS GIS, you can use [v.edit's](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/v.edit.html) snap tool.

> snap: Snap vector features in given threshold

There are options to snap to a node or a vertex.